# How to extend Ubuntu's home partition by taking unallocated space from HDD drive (Dual boot with 1 SSD and 1HDD)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, gparted

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS already installed in my SSD. This SSD also has windows on it. I have around 46gb for the Ubuntu's root partition and 52gb for the home partition.

I want to extend the home partition by taking the unallocated space that I had created in the HDD already from windows.

But When I changed the disc in gparted I do not see the Ubuntu's root and home partition.

How Do I extend the space by taking that unallocated space from HDD?

**What I have tried**
As in this article: https://itsfoss.com/dual-boot-hdd-ssd/ I tried to create a new partition with that unallocated space but stopped because I am not sure whether it will extend the home partition or will it create a new partition?

I want to know whether I can extend the partition or do I have to create new partition.

This is the SSD in gparted
[image: SSD in gparted]

This is the HDD in gparted
[image: HDD in gparted]

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. You can extend the sda7 partition to include the extra 10Gb at the end of the SSD, but you can't "extend" the partition to include space on another drive. You can, however, create a 100Gb partition on the HDD and mount that onto a mount point inside /home, giving you 100Gb extra space there.

Comment: @Jos I know about that 10gb I have that for root partition not for home which I will find a way to extend with the root because we only grow left & right. I did not know that we could mount a partition like you told. Could you please share some guide or help me with how I can do that

Comment: far better option is to use the SDD for `/` and not have a separate `/home/` Leave it empty and put your personal files on the HDD (there is a file in `~/.config` that allows you to do that. Makes it a lot easier to re-install your OS as  your base is on the SDD. 100Gb for `/` is excessive. You could take 50Gb from `/` and give it back to windows if you want. Do NOT use the sdd and the hdd to mix your base system That will result in crashes in time (the hdd will likley not spin up quickly enough for the base system to expect it to be avaliable)

Comment: Another alternative is to keep /home on SSD, but have a data partition with some or all of the folders in /home. Then mount partition & link folders back into /home, so it looks like data is in /home but really is in data partition. May not work well with some Snaps, but I refuse to use snaps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk